# Prove or disprove $A^B\subseteq C^D\iff A\subseteq C\land B\subseteq D$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Where $A^B$ is the set of functions from $A$ to $B$. I just don't know where to start. Just a little help would be great.

Comment: $f : A \to B$ is in general not equal to a function $C \to D$, if $A \subseteq C$, $B \subseteq D$. So it does not seem to hold.

Comment: The condition requires A = C.  Your definition for a set of functions is the opposite of the usual notation.

Comment: There are *many* ways to disprove this from both directions using several different counterexamples.